# gps device data receiving and interpreting it

Tags: gps, gpsd, gps-time, opengts

I bought a GPS device (GT02A) for realtime tracking of a vehicle. Now,I want the data sent by this device (such as longitude and latitude) to be sent to my SQL database in realtime, from where a client application will be able to access and perform calculations on the data. I have decided to use this software for receiving data from the device and transfering it to my database :-
http://www.aggsoft.com/gps-tracker-data-logger/

My first question is, am i using the correct software to solve my purpose? or are there better easy to use freely available softwares?

I connected my device with the above mentioned software and started receiving data. The data i receive is of this format:
(027042575977BR00150315A2230.9982N08819.7442E000.3180425295.9200000000L00000000)

Now, what i understand is that the fullstop is a delimeter for each parameter of data sent by the device.  the first part is the IMEI number of the device(7042575977). 
My second question is, which is the longitude and latitude from among other data?? what is the value of the cordinates? which format is that in? I just cannot uderstand the data.
The device sends date time speed direction also along with the coordinates. how do i understand that from the packet received?

for more info on data packet format you can also refer to page 6 of  http://www.iconcox.com/uploads/soft/140916/1-140916013353.pdf

But, Please help me understand the data and how i can send it to my database tables in the way i want.
Please help, this is very important for me.
Answering any of the questions or any sort of help on information is greatly appreciated.
Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question depends on your needs. If you only need basic information to be logged, I would suggest you take the NMEA sentence RMC (Recommended Minimum Specific GNSS Data), and store it in the database. No need for any software except a simple script. RMC includes time, date, latitude, longitude, speed and heading. If you need altitude, you also have to read the NMEA GGA sentence which gives you time (but not the date), latitude, longitude and altitude (among other data).

Your second question… I’m guessing, but if you live 7 km south east of Netaji Subhas Chandra Bose International Airport, in Kolkata, West Bengal, India, (Alipore Road) your latitude is 2230.9982N and your longitude is 08819.7442E.  This is a compact format with the degrees, minutes and fraction of minute.  2230.9982N means 22 deg., 30.9982 min North.

Here is information about NMEA: http://www.gpsinformation.org/dale/nmea.htm

Edit: I'm not sure if you can get NMEA from your device, and if not you need to decode the data as it is.